# How do you split a list of numbers in two in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement merge sort in C# and so far I've been given a `private List<int> list;` to work with. I am approaching this solution from an OOP perspective.

I already have a method to add numbers to the list.

```
public void insertElement(int number)
{
    list.Add(number);
}
```

No suppose we have a list with the numbers *5,3,10,1,9,23,4*. What I'm trying to achieve here would be the following:

**list1** = 5,3,10,1      **list2** = 9,23,4

I managed to do Insertion Sort and I'll share it here so that you can get the idea of the type of method my Merge Sort solution should look like. Any hints or help?

```
public void orderInsertion()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int value = list[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
            {
                if (value < list[j]) 
                {
                    for (int k = i; k > j; k--) 
                    {
                        list[k] = list[k - 1]; 
                    }
                    list[j] = value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your insertion sort code is irrelevant to your question, which is "how to split a list into two". You need to show your code _to do the task at hand that you're asking about_, not an unrelated task you've already solved, and then ask a _specific_ question about a problem you had with this _relevant_ code.

Comment: using System.Linq you can simply do,  originalList.Skip(amountToSkip).Take(amountToTake).ToList().

Comment: What determines where you break the list?

Comment: You may want to think about not needing more than one list. When "splitting" just work with the indexes of of start/end of the parts of the list you want to look individually at instead of copiing the values into new lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do?

```
private List<int> list = new List<int>() { 5, 3, 10, 1, 9, 23, 4 };
            private List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
            private List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
    
            public void insertElement(int number)
            {
                list.Add(number);
            }
    
            public void orderInsertion()
            {
                int firstHalfCount = (int) Math.Ceiling(list.Count / 2m);
    
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i < firstHalfCount)
                    {
                        list1.Add(list[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        list2.Add(list[i]);
                    }
                }
    
            }
```